# Clang-formal off brace wrapping

Tags: c++, clang-format

I want to set my brace wrapping like this

```
Configuration::~Configuration()    
{
}
```

but when I set parameters

```
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass:      false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
```

it doen't work for me. Parameter "BreakBeforeBraces" set in Custom.

Comment: `AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine:None`?

Comment: No, It set in Inline. Is this the reason?

Comment: Probably. According to docs, `Inline` implies that it can also merge `Empty`. If you want to exclude empty function, try `InlineOnly`

Answer (score 0):

I think the parameter values should be reversed, this works for me.

```yaml
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BraceWrapping:
  AfterClass: true  # This is optional
  AfterFunction: true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
```

Because the place you want to break is after a function, but not a class, so we should have `AfterFunction: true`.

And you have to include the prototype so *Clang* could know it's a function.

**Before:**

```cpp
class Configuration {
    public:
    ~Configuration();
};

Configuration::~Configuration() {}
```

**After:**

```cpp
class Configuration
{
public:
  ~Configuration();
};

Configuration::~Configuration()
{
}
```